# Interface for Saving/Loading to a Collection

Tags: c#, collections, interface

I want to create a simple general purpose interface to Save data to a collection and Load data from a collection. Which of the following (or none) is most appropriate?

The collection could have many levels and these details would be hidden behind the interface.

Option A.

```
public interface ISaveToCollection<T,U>
{
    void Save(T element);
    U Data { get; }
}

public interface ILoadFromCollection<T,U,V>
{
    U Load(T index);
    V Data { get; }
}
```

Option B.

```
public interface ISaveToCollection<T>
{
    void Save(T element);
}

public interface ILoadFromCollection<T,U>
{
    U Load(T index);
}

public interface IHoldData<T>
{
    T Data { get; }
}
```

Option C. None of the above (along with reasons and an alternative).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "save", "load" and "data", but the `ICollection` interface already provides a complete API for any operations you may wish to perform on a collection.

Comment: Just implement the collection interface I mentioned above, and you can hide all the levels and layering you want in the implementing class. Why make a new interface?

Answer (score 2):

Please familiarize yourself with ICollection interface, it already has methods you are trying to write:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13%28v=vs.110%29.aspx